# padding + width

Tags: css

I have links with bottom border, in CSS like this:

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

I have problem because the 'padding' value is getting added to the width value and border bottom is too long:

http://screenshooter.net/9186066/advygxa

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Padding and width have a hard time coexisting; simply remove your width declaration. Since your anchors are block, they will automatically take up 100% width (including padding):

```
a {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

Now it should take up a 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

That's what padding does.  Look at how the layout model works: adjust accordingly.  If you're looking for a flexible solution then you need to remove the padding from the `a` element and add something like an internal `span` that has the proper margin within the `a` and other dials adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the div that contains the links.

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/zXmG3/

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine, check http://jsfiddle.net/GjMQe/

```
a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 30px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
```

}​

Perhaps you forgot to include a reset.css file in your template.

Check [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)

Comment: Are you looking in IE?  Padding is outside of width unless you're on IE and not in standards-compliant mode.  Reset doesn't change this.